# Is there a way to export the workflows

Tags: workflow

I am planning to take the list of all workflows, its rule criteria, evaluation criteria, Action (I need to take this only for 3 objects) but there are plenty of workflows for these 3 objects.

Is there a way to query or app exchange app to get this list..Then i am planning to compare it against the triggers and eliminate some redundant workflows.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the workflows into a metadata tool like Eclipse. That will give you an XML metadata file to start from. Not the most user-friendly way, though.

Alternatively, why not filter the workflow rules by Object in the normal list view. That will give you the list that you need. The actions will then have to be manually fetched but you can also filter them by object (although related record updates will not be found that way).

In general, since the use of workflows can be very broad, there will always remain a piece of manual work to figure out the exact business rules that the workflow is built for.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm 8 years late but you can export all your workflows (along with their fields, field updates, email alerts, etc) using HappySoup.io's new "Workflow Migration Info" tool, which is 100% free

https://youtu.be/X6k2msXeAgM